# Sonar preview mode all new issues

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to run SonarQube using Sonar runner in local dev box for pre-commit check. We have a central SonarQube server where a analysis is done every day and published to the dashboard. When we are running on local dev box everytime the the issue report contains all the issues as **new** hence incremental data is not available. I have also tried both incremental and preview mode but the result is some.

Please find below the version of the tools used.And also configuration files. Please let me know if some other data is required.

SonarQube version : 5.1
Sonar Runner version : 2.4

**sonar-runner.properties**

sonar.host.url=http://[central sonar server]:9000/

sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

sonar.login=admin

sonar.password=admin

**sonar-project.properties**

sonar.projectKey=myProj:myProj-master

sonar.projectName=MASTER_PROJECT

sonar.projectVersion=21.0

sonar.sources=./src

sonar.binaries=./bin/

sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

sonar.exclusions=com/**/test/*.java

sonar.skipPackageDesign=true

sonar.profile=SonarWay

sonar.preview.excludePlugins=devcockpit,buildstability,pdfreport,report,buildbreaker,views,jira,issueassign,scmstats

**Command Used :**

c:\sonar-runner-dist-2.4\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner -e  -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

Updated with additional properties tried as well. in sonar-runner.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved . 2 things fixed the issue.

1. Creating a user with the required permissions.
2. Installing "Issues Report" plugin

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is tied directly to your use of a local server.

The purpose of preview analysis is to allow you to compare your *local* changes with what's on the *remote* SonarQube server. Since your remote server is update every night, running your preview against it will show you the issues you've introduced that day. Instead, you're running against a local instance which gets updated with a full analysis... never? Which (if true) would be why *all* your issues show up as new.

To execute a preview analysis against your remote server, you will need both the global [Execute Preview Analysis permission and the project-level Browse permission](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) for the project in question.

If for some reason you're unable to get those permissions (which is possibly why you're running a local SonarQube server?) Then you'll want to do the same full checkout and analysis locally every night that's being done for the official, remote server. I.e. you'll probably have to set up a second, parallel architecture. In short, it's probably easier in the long run to nag to get the appropriate permissions on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks G. Ann for your reply. <br/>The problem which you mentioned is correct and it is running Full analysis everytime hence all are new issues. I tried with providing the admin user in the sonar-runner.properties which all the accessed still getting the same output. property which I used for and password are. <br/>sonar.login=admin <br/>sonar.login=admin